# SAML Assertion custom attributes

Tags: single-sign-on, saml

we are  using  IdP(not Salesforce IDP), and SFDC as the SP. For our use-case, we would like to pass additional attributes with the UserId, such as the Profile,for portals  with the request as another validation point for the IdP.

Is It possible to pass custom attributes in Saml Assertion ?

From all the documentation, it seems that we can only pass the UserId or the Federated UserId. Is this possible? If so, can you point me to the documentation or blog where i can do this?

Comment: what IDP are you using

Comment: I see that a [SamlJitHandler](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_interface_Auth_SamlJitHandler.htm#apex_Auth_SamlJitHandler_createUser) is passed the SAML attributes. But perhaps that is not relevant to your case.

Comment: We are using a Third Party IDP.The IDP is sending the standard attributes (FEd id,portel id )+Custom attributes. can the salesforce parse the saml assertion .we are using IDP